# Android Add PinIt Button using Pinterest Jar NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, integration, noclassdeffounderror, pinterest

I am trying to add the Pinit button to my Android App.  I have downloaded the SDK and copied the pinit-sdk-1.0.Jar into my Project/libs folder.  I'm even able to make the necessary PinItButton import to my code.  But for whatever reason, my XML isn't finding the Button widget, and so I tried to add it just using Java with this code:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.pinterest_layout);
        PinItButton pinit = new PinItButton(this);
        ll.addView(pinit);
```

I know this is the correct way to add something using code because I tested it by adding a generic Button first.  I run my project then, and it crashes on the line where I set up the PinItButton.  This is the error that my logcat spat back at me:

```
07-22 01:19:52.160: E/AndroidRuntime(32367): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pinterest.pinit.PinItButton
```

I believe that I'm understand what it is telling me, but what else should I be attempting then to create the PinIt button?  Any help would be great.  Thank you!

Comment: Right click on your project > Properties > Java Build Path (left pane) > does it show the pininterest jar file under Libraries?

Comment: It does not.. I'm assuming I should import it there then?

Comment: No go :(  Thank you for your suggestion though!

Comment: I see. You did Project > Clean after adding the jar? Also, `ll.addView(button);` should be `ll.addView(pinit);`

Comment: Ah sorry, I should edit my code.  That was from when I verified that i was correctly adding buttons though code and not xml.  I did do a clean after the jar was added as well.

Comment: project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export tab, make sure your lib is checked

Comment: That worked!  It was unchecked!  Thank you so much!  If you put that as an answer, I'll accept it and uprate it.  Thank you!

Comment: any jar file for pintrest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was @Kai who helped me figure out my problem.  I needed to check my libraries.  I did that by going to project --> Properties --> Java Build Path --> Order and Export tab, then checking the library and clicking OK.  My problem was then solved!

Comment: Why was this down voted? I explained in clear detail what I did, who helped and said that it worked.  Explain please

Comment: any jar file for pintrest